# Sampling distribution of $\frac{\bar{X}}{S}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

Suppose that I have a random sample $X_1, … ,X_n$ from a $N(0,\sigma^2)$ distribution. What is the distribution of $$\frac{\bar{X}}{S}$$ and what is it's standard deviation? Here $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean and $S$ is the sample standard deviation.

Comment: What do you mean by $S$?

Comment: $S$ should be sample standard deviation.

Comment: @ user64494 I edited the question, hope it is clear now.

Comment: The standard deviation is clearly a function of $n$ but not $\sigma$: I would guess slightly more that $n^{-1/2}$.  The distribution appears to be leptokurtic for small $n$, but I would guess that the distribution of  $\sqrt{n}\dfrac{\bar{X}}{S}$  converges to $N(0,1)$ as $n$ increases.

Comment: @Henry Right, so this is really just CLT. So I would get you get some type of student-t for a given $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) (see **Combination of two or more independent random variables**), $\sqrt{n}\dfrac{\bar{X}}{S}$ is  the Student's $t$-distribution with $n − 1$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Good find, this agrees with what we seem to have ferreted out in the comments.